# node.js mongojs findOne callback returning error as null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback, mongojs

Presently being driven up the wall by this error.

I am running a node.js app with the mongojs wrapper for mongodb. I Started mongod on the default port, then ran

```
var db = require('mongojs').connect('localhost:27017/my_db');
var users = db.collection('users');    
users.findOne({'fb_id' : fbUserMetadata.id}, function(err, user) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(user);
                debugger;

    });
```

however err and user are both 'null'. To my knowledge, err should be populated with some kind of data even if it doesn't find anything.

How do I get the callback function to work properly? Pardon the newbie question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the `findOne` query doesn't find at least one matching document, the second parameter of the callback (in this case `user`) is set to `null`.  It's not an error, so `err` is also `null`.  So what you're seeing is the expected no-match-found response.

**Update**

Note that [`findOne`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne) has been deprecated in the 2.0 driver, but its replacement also exhibits this same behavior:

```
users.find({'fb_id' : fbUserMetadata.id}).limit(1).next(err, doc) {
    // doc is null if a matching document wasn't found
});
```

Comment: So simple, yet couldn't find this on the API documentation.